# WordPress WP Query search

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to build a simple WP Query that comes up with matches for a text string in the post content OR tag. Right now, my search is only matching the content.

For example, I have posts that contain the word "English" in both the content and title of the post, but not tagged as "English". My WP query only pulls up the posts that have "English" in the post content, not the tag.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'Post',
    's' => 'English'

);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'Post',
    's' => 'English',
    tax_query =>  array(
        'taxonomy' => 'tags',
        'terms' => array("english"),
        'field' => 'slug',
        "operator" => "IN"
    );
 );
```